# How to make GetDate() and this query substract not 3 days but 1 hour only?

Tags: php, sql-server

How can I substract instead of 3 days but only 1 hour using the query below?

```
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('
    SELECT Class, TransferTime 
    FROM USERDATA 
    WHERE strUserId = ? 
      AND (TransferTime < (GetDate() - 3) OR TransferTime IS NULL)   
', $character);
```

I use MSSQL Server 2005.

Comment: Jesus man, no need to duplicate questions. Even when I answered you already on a comment

Comment: Try `AND (TransferTime < DateAdd(hour, -1, GetDate()) OR TransferTime IS NULL) `

Comment: look for DATEADD function